# If a linear operator takes an orthonormal basis to an orthonormal set, then is the orthonormal set a basis?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T:H\rightarrow H$ be a bounded linear operator which takes an orthonormal basis $x_i$ to an orthonormal set $y_i$, i.e., $y_i=Tx_i$ for all $i$. Then does $y_i$ form a basis? This is trivial for finite dimensions, but what about infinite-dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

No, not necessarily.
Consider the operator $T:\ell^2\to\ell^2$
that satisfies
$$
T e_i = e_{2i}
$$
for all $i\in\mathbb N$, where $\{e_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$
is an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is an obvious counterexample for infinite dimensions.

**Hint:** Is every injective map from the positive integers to the positive integers also a bijection?

> Let $Tx_i = x_{i+1}$.